# Synchronizing two videos with Video.JS

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js, async.js

Ok so I have two video.js players (canv1 and canv2) each playing a copy of the same video. I want to pause canv2 at a certain timecode of canv1, then at a later timecode of canv1, sync canv2 with canv1 and play.

The goal being that canv2 can pause itself then catch itself up to canv1. Problem is, I'm running into issues with my sync function. There's some sort of lag and so when I sync I lose 7 to 10 frames of video.

So here's the concept. This code uses the Video.JS API. https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md

```
var conchShell = canv1; // Lord of the Flies, Bitch!

// Accepts player objects as arguments - canv1, canv2
function pause(){ 
    for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++){
        arguments[i].pause();
        console.log( arguments[i] + '1 is paused' ); /* TODO: REMOVE CONSOLE LOGS BEFORE DEPLOYMENT */
    }
}   

function play(){    
    for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++){
        arguments[i].play();
        console.log( arguments[i] + '1 is playing' );
    }
}

function syncToConchShell() {
    for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++){
        arguments[i].currentTime(conchShell.currentTime());
        console.log( arguments[i] + 'was synchronized with' + conchShell );
    }
}
```

conchShell is the player that has the master timeline, to which the other player syncs.
So the problem is that when I run the sync function, the conchShell video still ends up 5 to 10 frames ahead of the video I'm trying to sync to it. I assume that this is due to the amount of time it takes to run the sync function. i.e.- the videos were perfectly in sync for a fraction of a second but before canv2 gets caught up, conchShell is already a few frames ahead.

so the question is: Is there an easy way to figure out how much time a function took to run? because if there is I could just append that time to the timecode on canv2 and we're golden.

**UPDATE:**

OK, I've tried some other things. I'm using the async library now and having a little more success. My only problem is that its throwing a "object is not a function" error on line 505 of async.js. as far as I know, this is usually an error that is thrown for a missing semicolon.

anyway, here is a live version of what I've got right now. check out the code if you'd be so kind

http://staging.15four.com/videotest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no info if you are using HTML5 video or Flash fallback. Do you have problems in both?
One problem I have experienced with Flash player is that it doesn't allow perfect seeking - so almost always you are few frames off.

Answering your question: there's easy way to measure how long function took:

```
var start = new Date();
// some code to measure
var end = new Date();
var diffMs = end - start;
```

However I don't think that it can solve your problem.

If you care only for HTML5 video then I can suggest you different possibilities:

1. [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/demos) library was made for synchronizing video with content, I haven't seen working example with two videos though.
2. There's a prototype of [mediagroup.js](https://github.com/rwldrn/mediagroup.js) on GitHub - library for synchronizing videos.

The second one is interesting - they are using `requestAnimationFrame` function and you should switch to it if you are using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` - it's much more accurate.

**UPDATE:**
Solution to your immediate problem with async:
The problem I have with your updated code in Chrome is: Object is not a function. I haven't used async.js before. But it seems you should pass array of functions or object to your async.parallel, probably like this:

```
async.parallel([
    function() {
        async.each(players, syncSingleToConch, function() {
            console.log('error with the each function');
        })
    },
    function() {
       conchShell.currentTime(arguments[0].currentTime())
    } /* ... more ... */ 
]);
```

However functions in `async.parallel` take callback parameter and I think this it what really async is all about. The same with iterators in `async.each` - they have item and callback as parameters. I can't help more cause I'm not a specialist in the topic. Maybe tag your question with async.js tag?

Comment: I like popcorn.js a lot, but I am sort of rolling my own because I need the functionality to work with the flash fallback as well.

The weird thing is that if I do

`function syncToConchShell() {
        pause(conchShell, canv2);
        canv2.currentTime(conchShell.currentTime());
        console.log( arguments[i] + 'was synchronized with' + conchShell );
        setTimeout(play(conchShell, canv2), 1000);
}`

it syncs perfectly. so I think that 1000ms wait allows the currentTime(); function to finish operating.